# Multipeer Connectivity automatic silent connection

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to create some iOS app which would be manageable by OS X app via MultiPeer Connectivity framework. I am a newbie with this framework, but everything works well so far and I am wondering if it is possible to automatically connect to peer if the connection is lost.

I went through some ideas here on stackoverflow and other websites, which recommend to use `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate` with its function `startBrowsingForPeers()` to start browsing for peers when I detect that peer has been lost (this detectin works also well for me).

In next step, this function should call a function: `browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?)` from `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate`, but in my case, **it looks the function `browser found peer` is never called. Any ideas?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the delegate correctly so your delegate method gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dgatwood Yeap exactly! Thank you. I just found it. :)

For others in case that you get to same situation - you have to delegate it correctly, for example in method which reacts on changing state of peer:

```
appDelegate.mpcHandler.autoBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser.init(peer: peerID, serviceType: "network")
appDelegate.mpcHandler.autoBrowser!.startBrowsingForPeers()
appDelegate.mpcHandler.autoBrowser!.delegate = self
```

Of course with appropriate definition of `autoBrowser:MCNearbyServiceBrowser?` in mpcHandler class or other class which is working with and inherits `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate` protocol ...